# Firefox video not playing MKV format

Tags: html, html5-video

I use below code:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="url.mkv" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This code work on chrome, but not work on firefox

I testing `video/x-matroska` and `video/webm` but not work

Comment: it's not supported yet !!

Comment: You could consider alternate solutions for playing an MKV video depending on your needs. One option might be to use a multimedia toolkit to either convert the video to a format supported in the browser (e.g.: FFMPEG, LEADTOOLS…etc) or maybe use a JS Video Viewer control in your page that is able to play the MKV video like the control from LEADTOOLS (https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/tutorials/multimedia/cross-platform/html5/js/playback-a-video-file.html), which is what I am familiar with as I work for that vendor.